# ISERROR seems to be ignoring #REF! generated by INDIRECT

Tags: excel, error-handling, excel-formula, excel-indirect

I am trying to create a reference to a separate sheet using *INDIRECT*. I also want to check this for errors, so I preface the thing by using *ISERROR*.

- **H1** is a date value, formatted as "nn m.d". In this case, 42574 returns **Sat 7.23**
- **'Sat 7.23'.D2** equals **100**

---

Let's say there's a tab named "Sat 7.23", and I would like to access cell D2. Using *INDIRECT* and converting the formatted date to text, I create this formula:

```
=INDIRECT("'" & TEXT(H1, "nn m.d") & "'.D2")
```

In other words, *INDIRECT* tells me to make the following reference:

```
='Sat 7.23'.D2
```

When the tab exists, this functions perfectly (it returns **100**). But... what if the tab doesn't exist? *INDIRECT* returns **#REF!**, which is to be expected. So, I throw an *ISERROR* in front of it:

```
=ISERROR(INDIRECT("'" & TEXT(H1, "nn m.d") & "'.D2")
```

This returns nothing (or I guess **FALSE**), even though *INDIRECT* is generating a **#REF!** error and therefore should be **TRUE**.  Should it not?

To go further:

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDIRECT("'" & TEXT(H1, "nn m.d") & "'.D2")),0,INDIRECT("'" & TEXT(H1, "nn m.d") & "'.D2"))
```

In this case, *ISERROR* is always true, so this *IF* always goes to it's "else" statement. Since the reference is invalid, the whole *IF* statement returns **#REF!**

Comment: a) Shouldn't that be `='Sat 7.23'!D2` ? (note exclamation mark and not period) b) Shouldn't that be [IFERROR](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) and not `=IF(ISERROR(...` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what regional language uses *nn* to represent Sun - Sat in a format mask but *ddd* is used in an EN-US system and there is an exclamation mark between the worksheet and the cell address.

```
=IFERROR(INDIRECT("'"&TEXT(H1,"ddd m.d")&"'!D2"), 0)
```

This will return zero when copied to one cell above (`#REF!` on H0 as a cell address).

Comment: Thank you so much! For some reason, the reference was working with a period instead of an exclamation mark, so I don't know what's up with that.

"nn m.d" still works, so the formatting ultimately had no effect on the issue?

Comment: I do not know your regional language or system settings but if `=INDIRECT("'" & TEXT(H1, "nn m.d") & "'.D2")` works for you then more hte power to you. It certainly doesn't work for me and without specific region settings, I am unwilling to second guess the person that asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

Some amends as proposed below should help you see through the issues:

1. Change the custom format of cell H1 which has the date value to "ddd m.dd" without the quotes. I see you have used "nn m.d" and it did not work for me.
2. Now, in cell I1 (adjacent to H1), let's try and pull the value of D2 from the sheet named 'Sat 7.23' by using the formula below:

   =IF(ISERROR(INDIRECT("'" & TEXT(H1, "ddd m.d") & "'!D2")),"sheet doesn't exist, put your appropriate text message here",INDIRECT("'" & TEXT(H1, "ddd m.d") & "'!D2"))
3. To do a negative check, I recommend putting another date 'Sun 7.24" in H2 and use the same formula in I2 with a reference to the date in H2:

   =IF(ISERROR(INDIRECT("'" & TEXT(H2, "ddd m.d") & "'!D2")),"sheet doesn't exist, put your appropriate text message here",INDIRECT("'" & TEXT(H2, "ddd m.d") & "'!D2"))

This is what it will look like in a completed worksheet:
[image: Excel-INDIRECT Formula Usage]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed similar problem by generating error

```
=IFERROR(QUERY(INDIRECT("'"&I2&"'!B3:E", TRUE), "select E where B = '"&I5&"'),"-")
```

Gives **#REF!**

```
=IFERROR(QUERY(INDIRECT("'"&I2&"'!B3:E", TRUE), "select E where B = '"&I5&"')*1,"-")
```

**Works** because multiplication of REF! with 1 gives an error

If you expect a number go with *1

If you expect string go with &''